# How to set the display length for overlong candidate words in the candidate pop-up window in Fcitx5?

Tags: fcitx

I have some custom input words that are very long, and I want to display only the first few characters in the pop-up window, and use ellipses to represent the remaining characters. Does Fcitx5 support this feature? How can I set it up? My system is Ubuntu 22.04. The following is an example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKK9D.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the fcitx5 has this configuration panel, but fcitx (version 4.x) has it.

[image: fcitx-conf]